# Эффект для Android - scrolled blur

Tags: java, android, design, blur

Как можно сделать [подобный эффект](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JjoLaBh6fg&feature=youtu.be) в приложении на Android?
Видел такое в одном приложении на iPhone, теперь хочу и у себя сделать так же.

Это библиотека какая-то или можно штатными средствами сделать?

Comment: http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы установить blur эффект любому view элементу, легче всего будет использование этой библиотеки [500px-android-blur](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur)

**Например:**

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
blurringView.setBlurredView(layout);
```

Comment: Эта библиотека (500px) уже используется в моем приложении на Android, я хочу понять, как сделать такой ролик, который "ездит" туда-сюда. Его (этот ролик, имею в виду) можно сделать при помощи штатных средств?

Comment: @instajava, [это должно помочь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Есть много библиотек, можно естественно и самому напилить. Если вы не работаете с графикой или пока слабо в этом разбираетесь, очень рекомендую первый вариант. Почему? Вкратце этот эффект довольно легко получить, но проблема будет в оптимизации кода, так как это нужно отрисовывать и эта сильная нагрузка на UI поток.

Но логика проста: Вам необходимо получить область картинки которую вы будете отрисовывать, отрендерить (изменить) её, и вставить в закрывашку, которую будите использовать. Вообще у android есть свои методы blur, в рендеринге, думаю в библиотеках именно они.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Я думаю, мне подойдёт библиотека, которую предложили в комментариях, поскольку сам я неопытный программист.